# Sanic/gunicorn log file not created

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging, sanic

I have a python application deployed locally and on server. on my local instance I am unable to log console output in a specific location.... due to some reason I have to use `sanic==0.8.0` here is what I have done so far

app_runner.py

```
from app_name import create_app_instance
from sanic.log import LOGGING_CONFIG_DEFAULTS


app = create_app_instance()

custom_logger = LOGGING_CONFIG_DEFAULTS
custom_logger['handlers']['access_console']['filename'] = '/Users/username/root.log'
custom_logger['handlers']['console']['filename'] = '/Users/username/access.log'
custom_logger['handlers']['error_console']['filename'] = '/Users/username/error.log'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,log_config=custom_logger, access_log=False)
```

contents for custom_logger variable

```
{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'formatters': {'access': {'class': 'logging.Formatter',
                           'datefmt': '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]',
                           'format': '%(asctime)s - '
                                     '(%(name)s)[%(levelname)s][%(host)s]: '
                                     '%(request)s %(message)s %(status)d '
                                     '%(byte)d'},
                'generic': {'class': 'logging.Formatter',
                            'datefmt': '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]',
                            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(process)d] '
                                      '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'}},
                'handlers': {'access_console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                                 'filename': '/Users/username/root.log',
                                 'formatter': 'access',
                                 'stream': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>},
                'console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                          'filename': '/Users/username/access.log',
                          'formatter': 'generic',
                          'stream': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>},
                'error_console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                                'filename': '/Users/username/error.log',
                                'formatter': 'generic',
                                'stream': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>}},
                'loggers': {'root': {'handlers': ['console'], 'level': 'INFO'},
                'sanic.access': {'handlers': ['access_console'],
                              'level': 'INFO',
                              'propagate': True,
                              'qualname': 'sanic.access'},
                'sanic.error': {'handlers': ['error_console'],
                             'level': 'INFO',
                             'propagate': True,
                             'qualname': 'sanic.error'}},
                             'version': 1}
```

app.py

```
...
from sanic.log import logger
from sanic import Sanic
...

def create_app_instance():
     app = Sanic(name = "app-name")
     .....
     @app.route('/api_end_point', methods=['POST'])
     async def get_app_fn(request):
         ....
         logger.debug(f"URL:          {request.url}")
         logger.debug(f"PAYLOAD:      {request_payload}")
         ....
         return result
    return app
```

local console is as follows

```
[2021-09-03 15:18:34 -0700] [67681] [DEBUG] URL:          http://localhost:8000/api_end_point
[2021-09-03 15:18:34 -0700] [67681] [DEBUG] PAYLOAD:      {.....'Key':'Values'.....}
[2021-09-03 15:18:34 -0700] [67681] [DEBUG] ======Hitting Cache======
```

but there is not a single log file created at specified location

```
~ pwd
/Users/username

~ ls | grep *.log
zsh: no matches found: *.log
```